# Mono can't load ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll

Tags: c#, macos, mono, servicestack

Using Mono on OS X (MDK 3.2.3) and NuGet installed according to [MonoMVC's instructions](https://monomvc.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/nuget-on-mono/), I've tried to follow [the "your first webservice" tutorial in ServiceStack's documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice). This tutorial assumes IIS and Visual Studio, neither of which exist in my environment, and after several hours of searching for solutions on the internet I've done the following extra steps which they don't mention:

- Wrap the `web.config` example in a `<configuration>` tag.
- Put the source code for the Hello classes in a folder called `App_Code`
- Copied all of the `.dll` files that NuGet downloaded into a folder called `bin` with

  `find . -iname '*.dll' -exec cp {} bin \;`
- Use `xsp4` from the root folder of my project to host a development server.
- Copy `System.Core.dll` from `lib/mono/4.5` to my project's `bin` folder.

When I try to visit `localhost:8080`, I now get this error message:

> **System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException**
>  CS1684: Reference to type `ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IResolver` claims it is defined
>   assembly `ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=3.9.60.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null`, but it could not be found

How do I resolve this error?

---

**Edit:** Removed references to the *Missing method .ctor* errors, as they're unrelated to the CompilationException above. They go away if I copy *System.Core.dll* from `lib/mono/4.5` to the `bin` folder, but the CompilationException remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error while building a ServiceStack project on linux.  The project itself didn't reference an assembly directly that (I believe) a referenced assembly had referenced.

I added a reference to the assembly directly to the main project and the error went away.

My repo is here: https://github.com/MarFarMa/ServiceStack.Hello -- it builds and runs successfully on ubuntu - in case you want to try it instead of the tutorial you've been following.

Comment: I've tried to reverse-engineer your repository to see why it works & my code doesn't. Switching ServiceStack from the 3.9.64 nuget originally defaulted to to the 3.9.59 in your packages.config gets rid of the error in my question, but you're also pre-compiling your Global.asax.cs, so I guess I need to figure out how to do that next.